# Consuming Webservice fails with 'SRT: Unsupported xstream found: ("HTTP Code 200 : OK")'

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, webservice-client, sap-basis

I'm trying to consume a SAP WebService using Zend_Soap_Client
and getting the error

> SRT: Unsupported xstream found: ("HTTP Code 200  : OK")

Does this mean the call of the WebService method works,
but I (respectively Zend/PHP) can't handle the response?

Do you have any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the error is on the SAP side (SRT = soap runtime). According to SAP's documentation this problem is usually caused by an incorrectly configured HTTP destination.
Check the webservice using the `soamanager` transaction and see if the endpoint is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check the request header for the content type. It should be something like below:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using PHP's built-in SoapClient class, I got the same error, due to mismatching soap protocol version. I tried with 1.2, the endpoint was configured to 1.1.